# How to get all posts by all matching tags in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags, posts

I'm trying to get all related posts on a single template. Posts should have at least one matching tag.

```
$post_id = $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object_id();
$tags = get_the_tags( $post_id );
if ($tags && !is_wp_error($tags)) {
    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $tag_ids[] = $tag->term_id;
    }
  $args = array (
      'tag__in'      => $tag_ids,
      'post__not_in' => [$post_id]
  );
  $related_tags_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Here is where I'm printing the posts.

```
<?php   while ($related_tags_posts->have_posts()) : $related_tags_posts->the_post() ?>
                <?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But it's printing just one post from each matching tag. How do I print ALL posts that have matching tags? Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look below:

```
<?php 
  $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
  if ($tags) {
    echo 'Related Posts';
    $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
    $args=array(
      'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
      'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
      'posts_per_page'=>5,
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```

I hope it would help you out.